# How to use Platinum UPnP in Android?

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, shared-libraries, upnp

I've successfully build the Platinum UPnP stack (6.4.690 and NDK r4b) for and Android and ended up with a libPlatinumJNI.so file.

And now I'm wondering how to add/ use this the library in the code in my Android project.

Anyone has any idea ?

UPDATE:

I have asked the creator of Platinum and he told me that the intermediate layer for android is on his todo list.

Thanx

Comment: Adding the library to your Android project is as easy as putting the .so under <porject>/libs/armeabi.

Comment: please provide the .so file, so that I can use it in sample project and then post the code